# Firestore; add user email identifier without creating a collection

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning to create a web page (lets say for admin) to add user identifier only which is using email and create a temporary password for user without creating a collection.

I'm considering to either use python or java language but I couldn't find any answer whether this can be done or not with cloud firestore. does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can create users for your firebase app without adding them to a collection.
Firestore Admin SDK supports  Node.js, Java, Python, Go, C# and .NET it really depends on what language you wish to use for your web server. It could really be either that you choose or you could not use an SDK and instead use something completely different because you can also use firestore with javascript. It really depends on your requirements.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment) is more information on how to set up your environment for which ever option you may need.

To create a user with an email and a password you can use this code in:

### javascript

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

### Python

```
user = auth.create_user(
    uid='some-uid', email='user@example.com', phone_number='+15555550100')
print('Sucessfully created new user: {0}'.format(user.uid))
```

### Java

```
CreateRequest request = new CreateRequest()
    .setUid("some-uid")
    .setEmail("user@example.com")
    .setPhoneNumber("+11234567890");

UserRecord userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUser(request); System.out.println("Successfully created new user: " + userRecord.getUid());
```

More information on creating users with email [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account)